# Flutter JSON Serialization - *.g.dart files Not getting generated

Tags: windows, android-studio, dart, flutter

I used the json serialization dependency but unfortunately the g.dart files are not getting genereated. I tried some of suggestions  from stack but nothing worked.When I ran **flutter pub run build_runner build**  ,android studio terminal showed this error : *'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.* Then I tried to add the flutter to environment variable but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all the stackoverflow solutions they are saying to add flutter sdk path to variable .I tried adding it in the studio File>Settings>Tools>Terminal>Environment variables, but this didn't work. Then I tried to add the flutter sdk path to system variables from Control Panel\System and Security\System -> Advanced system settings from the menu on the right.[image]

**Click the edit options and add the flutter sdk path**

[image]

**Add new variable path, in my case it was  C:\Users\abr\documents\flutter\bin**